# Invalid Verb on WMIC get variable

Tags: batch-file, scripting, delimiter, wmic

I am trying to get just the primary hard disk serial number to a variable to be `echo`ed later.

I have used this and it works:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%k in ('WMIC path win32_physicalmedia get serialnumber /value') do (for /f "delims=" %%l in ("%%k") do set "SerialNumber=%%l")
```

However, it only does the last serial number and I want to get the primary.

If I used this command,

```
"wmic path win32_physicalmedia where tag='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0' get serialnumber /value"
```

then I get only the desired serial number.

Problem is when I try to modify the working code I get an error when running the bat:

> Invalid Verb.

Trying to get to work:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%k in ('wmic path win32_physicalmedia where tag='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0' get serialnumber /value') do (for /f "delims=" %%l in ("%%k") do set SerialNumber=%%l)
```

Errors:

> Invalid Verb

If I run just:

```
wmic path win32_physicalmedia where tag='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0' get serialnumber /value in CMD
```

I get the following output:

```
SerialNumber=     WD-WCC2E1XJADRT
```

So I know the command works.

It doesn't even matter if the spaces are in, I just want whats after the **`=`**. I am doing this in WINPE with WMIC support, so Powershell isn't an option.

### Total script

```
@echo OFF
setlocal
for %%v in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do if exist %%v:\drives.txt set w=%%v

for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%k in ('wmic path win32_physicalmedia where tag='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0' get serialnumber /value)') do (for /f "delims=" %%l in ("%%k") do set SerialNumber=%%l)

for /F "tokens=2" %%i in ('date /t') do set "Date=%%i"
echo %SerialNumber%,%Date% >> %w%:\drives.txt
```

Comment: I guess escaping the equal-to sign like `^=` should work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you modify your command to this:

```bat
WMIC Path Win32_PhysicalMedia Where "Tag='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0'" Get SerialNumber /Value
```

The **`=`** will be protected.

Try it like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%A in ('
    WMIC Path Win32_PhysicalMedia Where "Tag='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0'" Get SerialNumber /Value 2^>Nul
') Do For %%C In (%%B) Do Set "SerialNumber=%%C"
Echo [%SerialNumber%] & Pause
```

I've added the last line just to show any returned variable and value.

Comment: I never even considered that Tag = to be the culript. Thanks so much!

Comment: The quoted Tag fixed it, however I wanted to point out the Tokens=1 in your script output just "SerialNumber" since it was before the first delim. I still needed the Tokens=2 to get the actual serial number, for anyone else who may use this.

Comment: @IndigoAtaxia: no, you don't. `tokens=1*` means there are two tokens. Token1 (`%%A`) is what you'd expect, `*` is token2 (`%%B`) is "all the rest" (not delimited any more). Useful, when the delimiter character *may*  be also part of the string.

Comment: TBF, I'll also take some responsibility for your misunderstanding @IndigoAtaxia, I like to unnecessarily change things out of personal preference, and the more correct syntax is, `"Tokens=1,* Delims=="`. Had I done so, you'd have more clearly seen the asterisk as another token.

Answer (score 1):

It would be so easy in powershell.  You can extract the zip for Powershell 6 (pwsh) on a fileshare for winpe.  https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.2.1/PowerShell-6.2.1-win-x64.zip

```
$SerialNumber = Get-CimInstance win32_physicalmedia | 
  Where tag -Match physicaldrive0 | Select -Expand serialnumber
```

Here's another .bat way ('%' are sql wildcards, you have to double them in a .bat file):

```
for /f "skip=1" %%i in ('wmic path win32_physicalmedia where "tag like '%%PHYSICALDRIVE0%%'" get serialnumber') do if not defined serialnumber set serialnumber=%%i
```

Comment: Yes I agree, however I am doing this in WINPE without Powershell Support. Adding the PS support would make the WIM too large.

Comment: If you wanted to, you could run PS 6 off a share.  It's portable.